# Creating a nested object with child in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a rails noob that's tryin to do something in his app.
My problem is:

I have a Corso model, a Libro model and an Annuncio model. Corso has_many Libro, Libro has_many Annuncio, Annuncio belongs_to Libro and Libro belongs_to Corso. I want a form where the user can create a Libro (that MUST be associated to a Corso) and meanwhile an Annuncio of that Libro must be created. I'm literally freaking out, I saw hundreds of discussions but nothing solved my problem. Every time I change something I get some different errors.

My focus is:
- how to pass the corso_id (I mean, the objects Corso are already defined in the db) to the new Libro when I submit the form;
-I don't see why a Libro object is created (all fields nil) but an Annuncio object doesn't. It seems like the code @libro.annuncios.build in LibroController/new is useless.

I hope you will help me to get this form working.

LibroController:

```
class LibroController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @corso = Corso.find(params[:corso_id])
    @libro = @corso.libros.build
    @libro.annuncios.build
  end

  def create
    @corso = Corso.find(params[:corso_id])
    @libro = @corso.libros.build(libro_params)
    if @libro.save
       redirect_to @libro
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @libro = Libro.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
  end



  private
    def libro_params
      params.require(:libro).permit(:titolo, :autori, :casa_editrice, :edizione, :anno_pubblicazione, :ISBN, :immagine, :corso_id, annuncios_attributes[:prezzo, :note])
  end
end
```

AnnuncioController:

```
class AnnuncioController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @annuncio = Annuncio.new
  end

  def create
    @libro = Libro.find(params[:libro_id])
    @annuncio = @libro.annuncio.build(annuncio_params)
    if @annuncio.save
      redirect_to @libro
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end


  private
    def annuncio_params
      params.require(:annuncio).permit(:prezzo, :note)
    end
end
```

Libro Model:

```
class Libro < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :corso, inverse_of: :libros
  has_many :annuncios, inverse_of: :libro

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :annuncios
end
```

Annuncio Model:

```
class Annuncio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :utente, inverse_of: :annuncios
  belongs_to :libro, optional: true, inverse_of:  :annuncios
end
```

Corso Model:

```
class Corso < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :facolta
  has_many :libros
  validates :nome, uniqueness: true
end
```

routes.rb (a little messed up)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'facolta/new'
  get 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'
  get 'users/new'
  get 'corso/index'

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'


  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]

  root 'facolta#index'
  get 'corso_new' => 'corso#new' 
  get 'libro_new' => 'libro#new'
  get 'about_us' => 'static_pages#about_us'
  get 'faq' => 'static_pages#faq'

  resources :facolta do
    resources :corso
  end

  resources :corsos, shallow: true do
    resources :libro
  end

  resources :libros do
    resources :annuncio
  end

  resources :user do
    resources :annuncio
  end
end
```

views/libro/new

```
<h1>FORM DI REGISTRAZIONE HERE</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for([@corso, @libro]) do |libro| %>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :titolo %>
        <%= libro.text_field :titolo %>
      </p>
      <p>  
        <%= libro.label :autori %>
        <%= libro.text_field :autori %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :casa_editrice %>
        <%= libro.text_field :casa_editrice %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :edizione %>
        <%= libro.text_field :edizione %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :anno_pubblicazione %>
        <%= libro.text_field :anno_pubblicazione %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :ISBN %>
        <%= libro.text_field :ISBN %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= libro.label :immagine %>
        <%= libro.text_field :immagine %>
      </p>

      <%= libro.fields_for :annuncios do |annuncio| %>
        <p>
          <%= annuncio.label :prezzo %>
          <%= annuncio.text_field :prezzo %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= annuncio.label :note %>
          <%= annuncio.text_field :note %>
        </p>
      <% end %>

       <%= libro.hidden_field :corso_id, value: params[:post_id]%>
       <%= libro.submit "Inserisci il libro", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "annuncios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "libro_id"
    t.string "prezzo"
    t.text "note"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["libro_id"], name: "index_annuncios_on_libro_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_annuncios_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "corsos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nome"
    t.integer "facolta_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["facolta_id"], name: "index_corsos_on_facolta_id"
  end

  create_table "facolta", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nome"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "libros", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "titolo"
    t.string "autori"
    t.string "casa_editrice"
    t.string "edizione"
    t.string "anno_pubblicazione"
    t.string "ISBN"
    t.string "immagine"
    t.integer "corso_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["corso_id"], name: "index_libros_on_corso_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email"
  end
```

EDIT: edited with @arieljuod advices

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to merge the `corso_id` here: `@libro = @corso.libros.build(libro_params.merge({corso_id: @corso.id}))`. ActiveRecord already sets the corso_id since you are doing `@corso.libros.build(...)`.

You also don't need that hidden_field with the Corso id since you already have that from the URL.

You may want to do `@libro = @corso.libros.build` on your `new` action too.

And finally, I think this is the main problem: this is wrong `belongs_to :corso, inverse_of: :corsos`, it should be `inverse_of: :libros`

Fix the other things I point out too to clean up your code.

EDIT:

to add a select do something like this:

```
= libro.select :corso_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Corso.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did what you told but still doesn't work. 
Errors that I got: "Couldn't find Corso without an ID" on the line @corso = Corso.find(params[:corso_id]), and also, when I go on the page that should shows the Libros of a Corso, it says "constant uninitialized LibrosController". Can you help me to fix this? I can't understand how actually I can assign an existing corso_id to a Libro that I'm creating with the form. I mean, how rails get this value if I never pass it?

Comment: I try to explain myself better. 
I want to create a new Libro from a button in the user profile, so I think that I can't pass the corso_id to the form by params[], because there isn't any corso.id set. So how should I pass this info to the form? I can't do a field "text_field :corso_id" that the user fills, because obv the user doesn't know the id of all Corsos.

Comment: You are passing the Corso object, on the form tag: `<%= form_for([@corso, @libro]) do |libro| %>`, the url will have the corso id. Controller names should be plural by convention "LibrosController", "AnunciosController", etc, just change the file name to libros_controller.rb and the class name to `class LibrosController < ApplicationController`. Check the *Controller Naming Convention" on the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention and the guide about nesting resources https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Ok, but the problem (hope I'm not saying something wrong) is that I go on the form page (views/libro/new) from the user profile (views/user/show), not from the page of a Corso. I mean, @corso.id is never initialized in this way. How could I fix this?

Comment: I can't answer that. Does the user belongs to a corso? if so you should be able to get the corso from the current user. Was de corso selected previously? then you should save some reference somewhere (maybe the session hash), can the user add libros to different corsos? then you should show a select or something like that. That question is not about the code, is about the business logic and that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Nope, the user doesn't belong to a corso. My structure is:
Corso has many Libro, Libro has many Annuncio, User has many Annuncio, Libro belongs to Corso, Annuncio belongs to Libro. So my problem is that Libro and User are not related, because the user can choose at which corsos add the libro but from his profile,(and so he doesn't relate with some corsos), and meanwhile have to be created an annuncio for that libro. I think that the last option you said is what I need. How could I implement a select of corsos in the form that creates a libro and an annuncio?

Comment: Check my edit, you can use the `select` helper and the `options_from_collection_for_select` helper